# Boost library not compiling in Netbeans with G++

Tags: c++, regex, boost, netbeans

Attempting to run some regex on some code, but the code does not compile with boost. The library was installed with Cygwin when I installed netbeans and the rest of it, and no other steps were taken. Instructions online were unclear on what else needed to be done, if anything, with regards to linkers or if everything was supposed to go outside of the box.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;

bool regexValidate (string expr, string teststring) 
{
    boost::regex ex(expr);
    if ( boost::regex_match (teststring,ex) ) {
        cout << "true";
        return true;
    //} else if (regex_match (teststring,regex("^\s*\d*d\d*\s*$"))) {
    //    cout << "true";
    //    return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    string  diceexpr = "^\\s*\\d{1,}d\\d{1,}\\s*$";
    string  teststr = "10d10";
    string  teststr1 = "1d10";
    string  teststr2 = " 10d10 ";

    cout << teststr << " is ";
    if (regexValidate(diceexpr,teststr)) {
        cout << " valid!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << " invalid!" << endl;
    }
    cout << teststr1 << " is ";
    if (regexValidate(diceexpr,teststr1)) {
        cout << " valid!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << " invalid!" << endl;
    }
    cout << teststr2 << " is ";
    if (regexValidate(diceexpr,teststr2)) {
        cout << " valid!" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << " invalid!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Given the following output.

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-CIS17A.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[ ... redacted ... ]/Inclass Experiments'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-CIS17A.mk dist/CIS17A/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/inclass_experiments.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[ ... redacted ... ]/Inclass Experiments'
mkdir -p dist/CIS17A/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -errors -Wextra    -o dist/CIS17A/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/inclass_experiments build/CIS17A/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol rrors; defaulting to 00401000
build/CIS17A/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char> >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char> > > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char> >':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/regex_match.hpp:50: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::c_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
build/CIS17A/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `assign':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/basic_regex.hpp:382: undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::c_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
build/CIS17A/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o: In function `ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_14c_regex_traitsIcEEEEEC1ES6_S6_RNS_13match_resultsIS6_S9_EERKNS_11basic_regexIcSD_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsES6_':
/usr/include/boost/regex/v4/perl_matcher.hpp:374: undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string>, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::string> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::c_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::c_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-CIS17A.mk:62: recipe for target 'dist/CIS17A/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/inclass_experiments.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/CIS17A/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/inclass_experiments.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[ ... redacted ... ]/Inclass Experiments'
nbproject/Makefile-CIS17A.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/[ ... redacted ... ]/Inclass Experiments'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a linkage error. Please verify following two things:

- Some libraries from the Boost set of libraries need compilation -
  among them the "regex" library. In particular, the linker needs to link your regex-related code with two Boost libraries - `boost_system` and `boost_regex`. Make sure they have been built.
- The way to tell the linker about these libraries is entirely the
  NetBeans responsibility - so you need to configure your project in
  NetBeans in such way, that it would pass information about the
  libraries names and location to the linker. I use to do that in my own Makefile, but there are other ways to do that as well. You can find a description how to do that in the NetBeans own Help subsystem - just look for the `C/C++ Project Properties Dialog Box: Linker` page. So, make sure you've configured your NetBeans project to access Boost libraries.

You can find more information [here](http://www.boerngen-schmidt.de/2013/07/installing-boost-1-54-0-c-libraries-in-cygwin/).